# Ruby code is not working. Ruby can't read my code.

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

Every time I open this on Ruby, Ruby just closes almost immediately because it can't read something in the code. So there's an error(s) in the code but I reviewed everything and couldn't seem to find it. I need some help to get this code working. Thank-you so much in advance!

```
Time.now=apply_time
if apply_time.month <=3
price=45 
elsif apply_time.month <=5
price=55 
elsif apply_time.month <=7
price=65 
else 
price=0 
end
puts 'The fee to apply for the competition is $ ' + price.to_s + '.00 when you apply on the date of today, ' + Time.now.to_s +'.'
puts 'If your fee came up as $0.00, then that is because the competition has ended. But do not worry, there is always next year!'
Sleep 20
```

Comment: 1) You don't tell in which environment you are. I remember that under Windows XP the DOS box closed immediately if running ruby.exe (?), and stayed open if running rubyw.exe (?) or something like that. 2) You have the same `puts` as in your previous question. `Time.now.to_s +'.'` : In Ruby + is a method or an unary plus, depending on how you write it, with or without a space. Type it in IRB : "NoMethodError: undefined method '+@' for ".":String" means that the parser tries to evaluate an unary plus for the string '.', but there is no unary plus defined in the class String.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288118/ruby-when-i-try-to-launch-a-script-it-opens-and-then-immediately-closes

Answer (score 3):

your first line is trying to assign `apply_time` to `Time.now`

try it the other way around:

```
apply_time = Time.now
```

By the way, if you run this from irb, you will see the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `apply_time' for main:Object
```

but even if you define apply_time ahead of time, you will get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `now=' for Time:Class
```

because you cannot assign a value to the current time without smashing up the Time class.