# When I try to launch a script, it opens and then immediately closes

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I am trying to make a simple ruby script. However, when I run it, the command line opens, and closes almost immediately. I had the same problem with a visual basic console application, so I'm not sure if this is a problem with command prompt.

I am running Windows 8 with Ruby 1.9.3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a Ruby problem, it's a Windows and "not knowing your OS and development environment" problem. The same thing would occur using Perl and Python also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common symptom when developing command line applications on Windows, especially when using IDEs.

The correct way to solve the problem is to open the command line prompt or PowerShell manually, navigate to the directory where the program is located and execute it manually via the command line:

```
ruby your_program.rb
```

This is how command line programs were designed to be executed from the start. When you run your code from an IDE, it opens a terminal and tells it to execute your program. However, once your program has finished executing, the terminal has nothing to do anymore and thus closes.

However, if *you* open the terminal, then *you* the one telling it what to do, not the IDE, and thus the terminal expects more input from you even after the program has finished. It doesn't close because *you* haven't told it to close.

You can also use this workaround at the end of your Ruby script:

```
gets
```

This will read a line from standard input and discard it. It prevents your program, and thus the terminal, from finishing until you've pressed return.

Similar workarounds can be used in any language such as C and C++, but I don't think they are solving the actual problem.

**However, don't let this discourage you!** Feel free to use `gets` while you are learning. It's a really convenient workaround and you should use it.

Just be aware that these kinds of hacks aren't supposed to show up in production code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running from the command line or as an executable. Try placing a busy loop at the end to see the output or wait for keyboard input. If you run outside a command line the command line exits upon completion of the script.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new to Ruby. I'm much more used to using Java/C# IDEs with built in run options.

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple It's fine it happened to me too when I started doing C++ development in Windows for the first time. Too used to Linux :P

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple I'd expect most Ruby IDEs and editors to have built-in run options as well. What are you using for writing Ruby?

Comment: One should use a good texteditor and a shell for learning ruby. really.

Comment: @Hisako Doesn't seem like a good reason for a downvote, text editor and shell are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I use notepad++

Comment: @Hisako Oh okay nvm then :P just wondering what the downvote was for since I didn't see anything wrong with my answer albeit not as detailed as the other one.